# How to show only javascript message in a page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a piece of code below where it displays a message if javascript is turned off:

`<noscript style='color: red'><img src="Images/warning-2.fw.png" alt="Javascript Warning" id="warningImage" name="warningSymbol"/> In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled</noscript>`

Now the message is displayed in the `noscript.php` page so what I have done is externalize it by using include() to make `include(`noscript`)` and I have included this in all of my php scripts as so:

Text.php (example)

```
include('noscript')

//rest of page code
```

Now what is happening at the moment is that if javascript is turned off, it displays the javascript message but it displays the reset of the code as well so it outputs all of the page features.

What I want to do is that if javascript is turned off, then I want it to display the message but not the rest of code below, I just want the javascript message to appear. Only when javascript is turned back on then can the user see the proper page showing the page features.

But how can I do this?

Comment: Do you *really* want to use backticks instead of string-delimiting marks? You should probably use `include('noscript.php');`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan sorry that was a paste mistake on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just have all of the code on the page wrapped in an element that is hidden, e.g.:

```
<body>
   <noscript>...</noscript>
   <div id="js">
      ...code here...
```

`#js` would have `display: none`.

Then, you can just have a simple script at the bottom of the page:

```
document.getElementById('js').style.display = 'block';
```

You could also load all of the content with ajax, but that would be overkill.  It's pretty common for websites to still show everything even when JS is required (Twitter does, for example).

Comment: agreed, but do you think the js should be best served in a `window.onload` function, or as a single line code?

Comment: @SamuelCook either put it in `document.ready` or right before `</body>` -- the latter tends to be preferred nowadays.

Comment: So your saying the code in noscript.php should be inserted in the main page itself or can I include the `include('noscript.php)` in the ...code here...

Comment: `include` has to be done in php code, not in html, but it's not really relevant how you do it.